# Provide instant feedback for multiple choice questions in Google Form using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google form created from google script. I am hoping to provide instant feedback when the respondents select one option in multiple-choice questions before they submitted the form. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: "_provide instant feedback when the respondents select one option in multiple-choice questions before they submitted the form_". Would you please explain in more detail exactly what kind of feedback, and the purpose of the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

### Google Form can give to the respondents limited instant feedback by setting up a validation rule and a help text.

This is possible for

- [CheckboxValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-validation)
- [GridValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/grid-validation)
- [ParagraphTextValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/paragraph-text-validation)
- [TextValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-validation)

### Sample:

```
function myFunction() {
  var form=FormApp.getActiveForm();

  // Add a checkBox item to a form and require exactly two selections.
  var checkBoxItem = form.addCheckboxItem();
  checkBoxItem.setTitle('What two condiments would you like on your hot dog?');
  checkBoxItem.setChoices([
    checkBoxItem.createChoice('Ketchup'),
    checkBoxItem.createChoice('Mustard'),
    checkBoxItem.createChoice('Relish')
  ]);
  var checkBoxValidation = FormApp.createCheckboxValidation().setHelpText("Select two condiments.").requireSelectExactly(2).build();
  checkBoxItem.setValidation(checkBoxValidation);
}
```

> For another kind of instant feedback you might look into creating a
>   custom HTML form as an alternative to Google Forms.